# How safe it is to use Tomato web interface of Linksys WRT54GL to install OpenWRT on it?

Tags: firmware, tomato, openwrt

I have Linksys WRT54GL with Tomato installed. Unfortently I can't use VLANs with this firmware, so I have to switch to OpenWRT (or DD-WRT). Is it safe to use web interface or I should use tftp way?

Comment: Are you connecting wirelessly? Whichever way you're doing it, none of your communications with the web UI actually touch the internet. If it's wireless, it'll be encrypted, and if it's wired, somebody would need physical access to the wire to man-in-the-middle you.

Comment: @Phoshi, from what I understood, skfd isn't worried about being attacked, but more about bricking his router.  I believe he's asking if it is okay to use the Tomato UI to flash the new firmware to the router.  And as a side note, its is recommenced by most of the 3rd party firmwares to always flash over a hard-wired connection, never over wireless.

Comment: @heavyd: Oh, completely misread that. Yeah, web UI is safe, at least, I've never had issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be safe upgrading to DD-WRT, or any other firmware for that matter, through the Tomato UI.

But, as an alternative, you can continue to use Tomato.  It does support VLANS, it uses them by default out of the box (if you go to your device list you will probably see at least one VLAN interface listed).  [Here](http://www.seiichiro0185.org/doku.php/blog:creating_a_seperate_guest_network_with_tomato) is a nice guide to help you setup your own VLANs.  It does take a little bit of command line work, but not much, and you can keep with your current Tomato setup.

Comment: Oh, so it lacks only _GUI_ support of vlans, that that's great!

Answer (score 0):

I have updated from the linksys firmware to dd-wrt, from dd-wrt to tomato, and probably a few other variants. I never had a problem with my 54gl